# A non-zero CPU ready (but host underutilized)

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm having an issue with performance on a Red Hat VM, seemingly related to a Java process that seems to be quite heavy on processing and data.  I'm been working through different things, but nothing has improved the performance so far.

I currently have this VM on a host, and have confirmed that I have leftover virtual processors once I calculate the core/socket/threads.

I don't understand how/why the "CPU ready" of the VM would be non-zero when the host is underutilized for vCPUs.

Won't a non-zero value potentially mean the VM is getting shifted around semi-randomly to different CPUs?

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious...  I guess I'd want to try to pin the VM to same vCPUs as a test.

Comment: Please describe the performance issue. How is the performance inadequate for the user? In general, what is the application doing, with how many threads? What is the CPU socket and core configuration of the host and guest? What version of guest operating system distribution (kernels and profiling tooling changed a bit over the years)?

Comment: An application based on Java runs 2x (or more) slower.  I believe most of it is single-threaded as it's quite a complicated system.  It's a newer HPE system so in the 64 vCPU range (with hyperthreading).  The VM is Red Hat 7 (tried with 6,12 and even 24 vCPUs).  I know I'm either not going to say enough (or say too much to describe the whole thing).  My main question/point is to ask about the ESXi "CPU ready" stat.  I wouldn't expect it to be non-zero when I haven't overprovisioned.

Comment: Can no longer edit...  This all started with a P2V.  We have a partner in a similar situation, and they are fine, but they use HCI (with local dedicated storage), and we do not (FC switching to a shared SAN).

Comment: Half the speed of what? What is your baseline for comparison?  And what is a typical value of CPU ready, 5% is quite a bit different than 50%.

Comment: I thought my question was simple...  Should an underutilized ESXi still have a non-zero CPU ready?  That's really all I want to know.  I'll see if I need to get into the whole back story as I continue to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware suggests a healthy [CPU %READY is "under 5%"](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2001003).  However, it can be non-zero even when CPU is not oversubscribed. It is possible for the hypervisor to not be ready on every cycle that the guest makes a request of it.

Whether this matters to performance as seen by the end user depends on an enormous number of variables, and is extremely specific to applications and workloads.